# Office 2007: How to sort an Excel Table from within a Word macro

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-word-2007, vba, sorting

I have written a Macro in WinWord2007 which lists styles and their properties in an Excel table. The table is made accessible by the following 3 lines:

```
Dim Oxl_Sheet As Object
Set Oxl_Sheet = CreateObject("Excel.Sheet")
Oxl_Sheet.Application.Visible = True
```

I can without problems write into individual cells of the table, for example:

```
Oxl_Sheet.Application.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = ActiveDocument.Styles.(iStyle).NameLocal
```

I would now like to sort the completed table from within the same Word macro, but I have found myself utterly unable to do so. In the following line, for example:

```
Oxl_Sheet.Application.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("I2:I356"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

the compiler complains that the Sub/Function "Range" has not been defined.

Can anybody give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

A few changes should get you running:

1) If you want to maintain the Excel sheet beyond the macro's run,
    move the line:

> Dim Oxl_Sheet As Object

to the top of the macro page, outside of any function.

2) To fix the compile error, include a reference to the Excel Library to define the range function:

- In the VBA editor, 'Tools' -> 'References...'
- Select 'Microsoft Excel <12.0 or 14.0> Object Library

3)   Change the syntax of the sort line to qualify which object the range refers to:

> Oxl_Sheet.Application.Sort.SortFields.Add
>   Key:=Oxl_Sheet.Application.Range("I2:I356"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues

Comment: Thanks a lot, jdh. I didn't think about explicitly including the Excel library. The included libraries are now: VBA, MS-Word 12.0, OLE Automation, MS-Office 12.0, MS-Excel 12.0. I tried then to implement point 3) of your suggestion but I'm told now: "Runtime Error 438 - Object doesn't support this attribute or method" (translation from German). Any idea?